# Mathematical methods?

Tags: discussion

I was disappointed that my [question about eigenfunctions of the fourier transform](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386/how-do-i-compute-the-eigenfunctions-of-the-fourier-transform-closed) was closed so quickly.  Given the ubiquity of the Fourier transform in physics, it seems like an excessively narrow view of "physics" to consider the question off-topic.  Or should we direct all 'math methods' questions to math.SE?

Answer (score 2):

I think that this site can benefit itself by allowing questions about mathematics which are directly related to physics. However, in the case of that particular question you're asking, it is a completely mathematical procedure in which the particular physics is not important to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the Fourier transform itself is math, and there is already a site for math questions. The fact that it is widely used in physics doesn't necessarily make it anything more than pure math.